# Add Drop Down List to Change Results Per Page for Search Core Results

Tags: web-part, search, search-results

Does anyone have an example of how to add a drop down list to the search core results web part to change the number of results?

Comment: You mean changing count of displayed items in paged results view?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to override the Core Results Web part, you can create a new one which implements the drop down values and then change the page size of the core results.

Here's an example picking the page size from the query string.

```
public class PageSizeWebPart : WebPart
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["size"] == null) return;
        WebPartZoneCollection zones = this.WebPartManager.Zones;
        foreach (var core in
            (from WebPartZone zone in zones
             select zone.WebParts
             into webparts
             from WebPart webpart in webparts
             select webpart).OfType<CoreResultsWebPart>())
        {
            core.ResultsPerPage = Convert.ToInt16(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["size"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Probably not optimal, but it works.